# What is the smallest multiple of $999$ with no $9$'s in it? we are considering positive numbers only

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

What is the smallest multiple of $999$ with no $9$'s in it?

I can't find one by bashing, and I've just been plugging them into a calculator... Are there any smart ways?

Note: Please post a solution that isn't the answer or a bash. I already know the answer, but not how to get it. Thanks!

Comment: why not  zero  ? no  $9$ at all

Comment: Well, I found that $112 \times 999 = 111888$ with one line of Mathematica code.

Comment: $999*112=111888$

Comment: How'd you get there? I don't want to bash that out.

Comment: Use that the multiples of 999 are of the form $k\cdot 1000 -k$.

Comment: Considering numbers of the form "$aaabbb$" divisible by $9$, it is easy to see that $111888$ is a candidate, but I have no idea to show that no smaller example exists.

Comment: @Errol Y. Got it! Thanks! (gotta subtract 112 for no 9's)

Comment: @Peter When I posted that *comment* (rather than an *answer*), the question had no such "requirement".

Comment: @MarkMcClure Sorry, didn't know that

Comment: No  problem and nice job!

Comment: @Errol.Y You had the crucial idea. Just write an answer, and I will upvote.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so I won't bother, go ahead if you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of positive integer $n$ such that $999n$ doesn't contain any digit $9$. 
Let $m$ be the smallest element in $X$ and "$....abc$" be its decimal representation. It is clear $c \ne 0$. Otherwise, $\frac{m}{10} \in X$ contradicts with the choice that $m$ is the smallest element in $X$.

Let "$...def$" be the decimal representation of $999 m = 1000m - m$.
Since $c \ne 0$, it is easy to verify $$(d,e,f) = (9-a,9-b,10-c)$$
Since $999m$ doesn't contain any digit $9$, we have 
$$\begin{cases}
d \ne 9 \implies a \ne 0 \implies a \ge 1\\
e \ne 9 \implies b \ne 0 \implies b \ge 1\\
f \ne 9 \implies c \ne 1 \implies c \ge 2
\end{cases}
$$
So the smallest possible candidate for $m$ is $112$. By direct substitution, $999\times 112 = 111888$ doesn't contain any digit $9$. This mean $112$ is the smallest number we seek.